# Why was Marcel assassinated?

Tags: counterpart-series

In Season One of [Counterpart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counterpart_(TV_series)) and in the Alpha universe, Marcel is promoted from Interchange to Strategy, and shortly thereafter is assassinated by Baldwin Prime.

In Season Two, when Howard Silk Alpha is sent to the Echo prison in the Prime universe, he meets Marcel Alpha.  Marcel Alpha holds a grudge against Howard (both Prime and Alpha) because Howard Prime extracted Marcel Alpha from the Alpha universe and put him in Echo while Marcel Prime took his place in the Alpha universe.

In short, we learn that the Marcel who was assassinated in Season One was an impostor from the Prime universe, and not the Alpha Marcel.  Yet he was assassinated by Baldwin Prime who went on to assassinate multiple Alpha characters to make way for their Prime impostors.

Why would Baldwin Prime have orders to assassinate Marcel Prime in the Alpha universe, especially when he'd recently been promoted into a valuable position?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that's the case at all.

In Howard Alpha's first conversation with the Peter Quayle in the Echo, we actually learn that *that* Peter is Peter Prime, and that most of the prisoners there are actually the *Prime* versions who have been captured so that Management can harvest information about them, presumably so that they can then use that information to covertly influence their Alpha counterparts in the Alpha universe.

The reason Marcel *Prime* in the prison holds a grudge against Howard is that he mistakes him for Howard *Prime*, who, as part of Section 2, extracted Marcel *Prime* from his normal life in the *Prime* universe to put him in the Echo prison in order to be used in that way - harvested for information in order to influence Marcel Alpha.

That all being said, it's still not entirely clear why Baldwin would assassinate Marcel Alpha, considering that Marcel Prime is *not* a sleeper agent, and is in fact in the prison.

Perhaps to create a vacancy for a sleeper agent?  After all, Baldwin was acting on orders from Indigo, not Management, who would presumably not want to assassinate someone who they were gathering information to influence.

Comment: God, you're right, I misinterpreted "kidnapping" to mean cross-universe, but it makes more sense if it wasn't.